# how to create folder and save document into alfresco using java delegate

Tags: java, alfresco

I am using alfresco community edition , In activity workflow one step i have to generate document automatically save into alfresco document library folder,I created document but when use to save document to document library i can't ,Please help with reference

Comment: I have a method that i used to create automatically a document with java are you interested ?!??

Comment: yes, I have tried but not create workspace in alfresco

Comment: You haven't specified whether you want to use JavaScript to create the document or Java. Both are options. Also I am not able to figure out exactly what the problem is from your post.

Comment: I want auto generating document directly save alfresco document library without authentication

Answer (score 0):

try this worked fine for me

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String serverUrl = args[0];
String username = args[1];
String password = args[2];
Session session = getSession(serverUrl, username, password);
Folder root = session.getRootFolder();
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, BaseTypeId.CMIS_
DOCUMENT.value());
String name = "New Document (" + System.currentTimeMillis() +
").txt";
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, name);
List<Ace> addAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
List<Ace> removeAces = new LinkedList<Ace>();
List<Policy> policies = new LinkedList<Policy>();
String content = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
ContentStream contentStream = new ContentStreamImpl("text.txt",
BigInteger.valueOf(content.length()),
"text/plain", new ByteArrayInputStream(content.
getBytes()));
Document newDocument = root.createDocument(properties,
contentStream, VersioningState.MAJOR, policies, addAces, removeAces,
session.getDefaultContext());
System.out.println(newDocument.getId());}
```